# Subset data frame to include only levels one factor that have values in both levels of another factor

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following df:

```
Subject Condition Score
 John      Hard     1
 John      Easy     1
 Simon     Hard     2
 Simon     Easy     3
 Mary      Hard     1
 Mary      Hard     2
 Kevin     Hard     2
 Kevin     Easy     3
```

I would like to subset this df to include only data from subjects that have completed both levels of the 'Condition' factor (i.e., Easy AND Hard). The resulting df should look like:

```
Subject Condition Score
 John      Hard     1
 John      Easy     1
 Simon     Hard     2
 Simon     Easy     3
 Kevin     Hard     2
 Kevin     Easy     3
```

I have tried the following:

```
dfNew <- subset(df, Condition==c("Easy", "Hard"), select=Subject)
dfNew2 <- subset(with(df, Subject, Condition == "Easy" & Condition == "Hard"))
```

But I received errors and warning messages for both.

Any help would be much appreciated.