# How to conditionally subset data by repeated group ID in R

Tags: r, group-by, conditional-statements, subset, subset-sum

I have a dataset with Id numbers that occur in multiple time points.

I want to select the IDs that exist atleast once in month 1-6, month 7-12, 13-18, 19-24, 25-31, **and** month 31-36.

ex.

```
id <- c('D1','D1','D2','D3','D3','D3','D4','D5','D6','D1','D1','D1')
month <- c(1,2,1,1,2,1,3,3,3,2,4,5)
cbind(id, month)
       id  month
 [1,]  D1     1
 [2,]  D1     2
 [3,]  D2     1
 [4,]  D3     1
 [5,]  D3     2
 [6,]  D3     1
 [7,]  D4     3
 [8,]  D5     3
 [9,]  D6     3
[10,]  D1     2
[11,]  D1     4
[12,]  D1     5
```

i want to select the ids that exist for month 1-3 and month 4-6. In this situation I would only want D1.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961347/subset-data-frame-to-include-only-levels-of-one-factor-that-have-values-in-both/44961891

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame("id" = id, "month" = month)
intersect(unique(df$id[which(is.element(df$month, 1:3))]), #IDs w/ month 1-3
          unique(df$id[which(is.element(df$month, 4:6))])  #IDs w/ month 4-6
          )
```

with output

```
> intersect(unique(df$id[which(is.element(df$month, 1:3))]),
+           unique(df$id[which(is.element(df$month, 4:6))])
+           )
[1] "D1"
```

Comment: I like the logic, but don't do `data.frame(cbind(...))` as you end up coercing all the numbers to character. Just `data.frame(...)` will do.

Comment: @thelatemail True, I also just noticed it. I probably should edit it.